# How to Access controls in the Silverlight DataGrid column Header template?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, header

I have a requirement where column headers are hyperlinks and the content of the hyper link is set in the code behind.

Here is my HeaderTemplate style for the datagrid columns.

```
<Style x:Name="dataGridHeaderCenterStyleWithLink" TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid Name="Root">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hlHeader" Content="Command 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="20"   Tag="Title"  />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So, in the code, I want to access the Hyperlink button and set the Content and Click event based on the column it is in. I came as far as accessing ControlTemplate in the Header Template. But could not figure out how to access the Hyperlink button in the ControlTemplate.

```
foreach (DataGridColumn c in grdData.Columns) {
                DataGridTemplateColumn xx = (DataGridTemplateColumn)c;
                Style sty = xx.HeaderStyle;
                Setter stt = sty.Setters[7] as Setter;
                ControlTemplate templ = stt.Value as ControlTemplate;
                ?????
            }
```

Appreciate any help/ suggestions???

thank you.

Nalini.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ChildrenOfType()` method..

```
var yourLink = templ.ChildrenOfType<HyperlinkButton>().FirstOrDefault( h => h.Name == "hlHeader" );
```